# Show the CMD window with Java

Tags: java, netbeans, cmd

I'm using this code to launch a .cmd file:

```
try {
            String line;
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myPath + "\\punchRender.cmd");
            BufferedReader input =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It works fine, but I want to actually see the cmd.exe window running.  How can I make it show?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of running your path, try actually running `cmd.exe` but using the build in `start` command to launch a new command window.  You can see the full set of command line arguments by entering the following at a command prompt:

```
cmd/?
start/?
```

in your case, you probably want to execute something like the command:

```
cmd /c start c:\path\to\punchRender.cmd
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is giving me the same result.  The CMD window stays hidden (but executes properly).  Any special tricks to make it show?

Comment: P.S. wow this is already showing up #1 on google for Java show cmd :)

Comment: OK, doing this from CMD.exe launches a new CMD window, so this should do it for you.

Comment: Perfect!  The start thing is just what I needed.  Thanks!