# Open up command line from Java application

Tags: java, windows, command-line

Is it possible to open a command line from Java application, meaning, I have a GUI (written in Java) and I want a command line window to open up (at a specific location) in some cases. is it possible to implement?

Thanks,
Binyamin

Comment: Do you just want to open a cmd window and have it stay there?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904/how-can-i-open-a-cmd-window-in-a-specific-location

Comment: I want to open a command line window and run a .bat file automatically, but even open the cmd will be good enough, as long as the user can see it and insert his input.

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666699/show-the-cmd-window-with-java

Comment: If he wants a platform independent command line then it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @dacwe - no. I need to open it from java application.

Comment: @Zevan - Seems like what I need. 10x

Comment: @dacwe - seems like a duplicate of some other thread :)

Comment: @MByD: Typical, I just wrote an answer! :)

Comment: @Goran Jovic: it's tagged "windows"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works (revised solution):

```
String path = "c:\\";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/C", "\"start; cd "+path+"\"" });
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. (But I don't think it's the same question.)