# Start external console application from Scala in interactive mode

Tags: scala

I am using scala.sys.process to start an external console application from within my Scala code. However, I hit a road block when the console app requires the user input.

Basically, when I start the console app with

```
Seq("powershell" , "myConsoleApp.exe").run
```

myConsoleApp.exe will not be started in its own "window". I can see the console app is running when I check the Task Manager. Without an actual window, I can't really key in anything.

I know Scala can return the program output to a String or a Stream[String] - I guess Scala will probably be able pipe input to the external process also.

But I really don't want to re-write such logic in Scala when all of them are already available in the external program.

I am wondering if there is a way to start an external console program in its own window? Or is this a shortcoming with scala.sys.process.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from this Java answer [Show the CMD window with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666699/show-the-cmd-window-with-java)

```scala
import scala.sys.process._   
Seq("cmd", "/c", "start", "PowerShell.exe", "myConsoleApp.exe") run
```

Comment: I have no any "cmd" in my system

Comment: @idonnie cmd is windows' shell.

Comment: @david-holbrook excellent, though I believe I found a shorter alternative to your solution: Seq("powershell", "Start-Process", "myConsoleApp.exe")

Comment: Could you post your solution for Unix-es with Bash shell? So I will check and upvote, then? ^)

Comment: @idonnie, I can try it with cygwin tmr and report back

Comment: Now by watching questions by defoo, I could manage do it myself, but if you do it - i will gladly appreciate

Answer (score 1):

After some more googling, I found that my problem is more in the way I call powershell.
Here is a solution that works for me:

```
Seq("powershell", "Start-Process", "myConsoleApp.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

This will run interactively from Scala console, copy and `:paste`

```
val con = System.console
new java.lang.Thread() {
  val in = new java.lang.Thread() {
    override def run() {
      while (true) { 
        Thread.sleep(1)
        if (con.reader.ready)
          con.reader.read()        
      }       
    }
  }
  override def run() { 
    in.start()
    while (true) { 
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      con.printf("\nHai")
    }
  }
}.start()
```

Comment: I believe your solution will run. Though, I would prefer to interact with a new console and leave the "scala console" for show log, event etc

Comment: I believe you could get instance of Console for newly created process using Runtime. If no - we are stuck.